Laravel: mcamara/laravel-localization in ServiceProvider
The following have different results
echo '<pre>'.print_r(app()->getLocale(), true).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r(app()->currentLocale(), true).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleRegional(), true).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale(), true).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleName(), true).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.print_r(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleNative(), true).'</pre>';

visit my http://example.test/en/admin/dashboard
In app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot(): void
{
    $languages = (new \App\Repositories\LanguageRepository)->newModel()->active()->get();
    view()->share('languages', $languages);

    //put those lines here
    echo ... 

The result is
en
en
zh_TW
zh_Hant
Chinese (Traditional)
繁體中文
In dashboard.blade.php
{{ app()->getLocale() }}<BR>
{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() }}<BR>
{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleName() }}<BR>
{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleNative() }}<BR>
{{ LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocaleRegional() }}<BR>

The result is
en
en_GB
English
English
en_GB
This is the same page. I can't find what went wrong.
laravellocalization.php
<?php

return [
    'supportedLocales' => [
        'en'          => ['name' => 'English',                'script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'English', 'regional' => 'en_GB'],
        'zh_Hant'     => ['name' => 'Chinese (Traditional)',  'script' => 'Hant', 'native' => '繁體中文', 'regional' => 'zh_TW'],
        'zh_Hans'     => ['name' => 'Chinese (Simplified)',   'script' => 'Hans', 'native' => '简体中文', 'regional' => 'zh_CN'],

    ],

    'localesMapping' => [
        'en' => 'en',
        'zh_Hant' => 'zh-Hant',
        'zh_Hans' => 'zh-Hans'
    ],

web.php
Route::group(  
    [  
    'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),  
    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ],
    'as' => 'lang.'
    ], function()  
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['auth:admin'],
    ], function ()
    {
        Route::get('', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

Why en, but zh_Hant ?

Because you are so noob
Primitive people who are not updating technology should not harm people in the programming circle.
